# Graph being squashed when stored in Quarto callout block where collapse=TRUE

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto, echarts4r

I am trying to produce a report using Quarto that "hides" some plots in callout blocks that can be expanded should users want to view the detail.

I am using the echarts4r package to create my plots, but they don't seem to rescale to fill the container when collapsing the block is chosen by default `{.callout-caution collapse="true"}`. The image below shows you what I mean once I try and expand the collapsed callout block.

[image]

The issue does not occur when `collapse=false` is the default, nor do I experience the same issue when using alternative packages (ggplot, highcharter) -- but I would ideally like to use echarts4r -- and I'm hopeful that it's a just rookie error/oversight on my part.

Here is a reprex if useful:

````
---
title: "Reprex Report"
format: 
  html:
    page-layout: full
editor: visual
---

```{r, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, include=FALSE}

library(tidyverse)
library(echarts4r)

df <- data.frame (Month  = c("Apr-23", "May-23", "Jun-23", "Jul-23", "Aug-23", "Sep-23", "Oct-23", "Nov-23",
                             "Dec-23", "Jan-24", "Feb-24", "Mar-24"),
                  a = c(18,44,70,45,69,68,52,54,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                  b = c(527,751,721,633,696,675,775,732,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                  c = c(14,23,28,4,2,14,18,30,NA,NA,NA,NA))

```

## **Activity**

::: callout-tip
## Description

Blah blah blah
:::

::: {.callout-caution collapse="true"} 
### Plot

```{r, echo=FALSE}

df %>%
  e_chart(Month) %>% 
  e_bar(a, stack = "groups", color = "green") %>%
  e_bar(b, stack = "groups", color = "red") %>%
  e_bar(c, stack = "groups", color = "blue") %>%
  e_labels(position = "inside", fontSize = 16) %>% 
  e_y_axis(name = "Activity", nameLocation ="middle", 
           nameTextStyle = list(padding = c(0,0,30,0))) %>%
  e_x_axis(type = "category", name = "Month",
           nameLocation ="middle", nameTextStyle = list(padding = c(20,0,0,0))) %>% 
  e_tooltip(axisPointer = list(type = "shadow"), 
            trigger = "axis",
            backgroundColor = "rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.75)", 
            borderColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)", textStyle = list(color = "#fcfcff")) %>% 
  e_grid(right = "2%", left = "8%", bottom = "10%", top = "5%")

```
:::
````

I have tried various combinations of changing the code chunk options (e.g., fig.width) and fiddling with e_grid() -- all to no avail.